# Where is the ClaimsPrincipal "User" created in MVC, visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity, claims

I have created an MVC Project, but implemented my own login functionality. 
In _LoginPartial.cshtml there is usage of the ClaimsPrincipal "User" methods such as User.IsSignedIn().
when i use my login function I want to update the ClaimsPrincipal "User" so that the shared view _LoginPartial.cshtml will be correct. i.e. I need "@if (User.IsSignedIn())" to work.
I cannot find where this "User" is created in the Project standard login, so I cannot override it. 
How can i add a claim to this already-defined-somewhere "User"? Where is it created during the custom login process?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to log in first so that Claims Principal "User" will be filled. Open Account controller added out of the box when you are creating new MVC project in VS2015 and take a look at SignIn action. 
When the result of`await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);`will be succeeded then you User property will be filled.